# What is the preferred approach for this problem?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series

I have the Data of 10,000 users Time Session in a website/App, The Login time, logout time, the person activity,

The Data is available for 60 days ( per user )

Using this 60 days data for 10k users, can I predict the active time of the respective user on 61st day? if yes what is the best approach and please suggest which type of problems I can refer to solve this

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to do with that information? Knowing how the prediction will be used may help people give you good advice.

Comment: What you have is a regression problem. That gives you two options depending on the data => time-series model or an ML model. I'd go with an ML model

Comment: are there 10K distinct user ? (I assume no) - how many users (different user_id) do you have ?

Comment: I would go in the clustering domain to see if you cannot group the different data

Answer (score 0):

Convert your training data to the following format -

```
a = login_time
b = logout_time
c = person_activity
train_data_X = [
               [[a, b, c], [a, b, c], ......, [a, b, c]]
               [[a, b, c], [a, b, c], ......, [a, b, c]]
               .
               .
               .
               [[a, b, c], [a, b, c], ......, [a, b, c]]
             ]

train_data_Y = [
                 [[time_day_1], [time_day_2], ...... [time_day_60]]
                  .
                  .
                  .
                 [[time_day_1], [time_day_2], ...... [time_day_60]]
                ]
```

Explaination -

You Input(training_data_X) data has shape `10000 * 60 * 3` because you have 10K users, data for 60 days and each data point depends on 3 variables namely a, b and c.
Your Target(training_data_Y) data has shape `10000 * 60 * 1` because you have just one number to output i.e active time.

Now, this is a Regression Problem because you are trying to predict a continuous value i.e active time.

You can model this type of problem with a number of time-series models. But since you got a multivariate input, i.e `[a, b, c](refer training_data_X)`. You would be benefitted a lot using a Seq2Seq model to generate your time-series. If just want to generate 61st time-step you could use it just for that as well.

[Specific details and implementation](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-multi-step-time-series-forecasting-of-household-power-consumption/)

Comment: you don't have user_id - do you ? then how does the model learn about each user_id activities ?

Comment: The first dimention i.e the `10000` rows or in this case matrices are your users. Assign any id to them.

Comment: 1) I don't see any user here -> a = login_time
b = logout_time
c = person_activity - yes, these are user information but do not specify which user - even if they are user_id, how does that gonna look after all those numerical transformation ? - 2) the link you have added at the end, is not repeated measurement - every household is in one row - in this question one user is not necessarily one row

Comment: 1st row is first user. 2nd row is second user.  Like sentences words and characters.

Comment: Only difference between the link I posted and the problem here is I additionally suggested dividing it day wise adding one more dimension to the "user" row

Comment: @ashtoush - exactly but when you deal with users Time Session in a website/App, each row is NOT necessarily for a unique user ! there could be a user with 100 rows (corresponds to 100 session across time).

Comment: We are talking about different things.  1. You can track users across sessions. 2. If you can't your algorithm just treats them as separate users. 3. Only think I see lacking in the aproach I suggested is that time would not have proper scaling