# What classification ML model can handle this data?

Tags: machine-learning

I have been trying to figure out a proper classification model for following type of data

```
    C1      C2       C3             C4          label
R1 [1,4,5]  [3,5,1]  [8,5,1]        [0, NA, 6]  lung
R2 [5,NA,5] [5,1,0]  [0.9, NA, NA]  [0, 0, 0]   lung
R3 [1,1,1]. [9,4,2]  [1,1,5]        [8,1,4]     colon
```

As you see, for every feature I have a series of values and to make it worse, sometime NAs.

It would be great if anyone can give me a few insights on which algorithm is best suited for such type of classification data and the things I should be careful about while interpreting the model results.

Thank you & stay safe

Comment: Welcome to SO. It seems like you have equal length lists as values to the columns. A good starting point would be to  convert all these values to individual columns.
This should help you in treating null values as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm concerned that this will treat each value of each feature as a new feature. I was kind of hoping to feed this directly to a model. Do you think that's not a good approach? Because, the combination of values of each feature actually defines it's specificity.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the classification algorithms generally need a numeric value to be able to classify correctly.
You can use Random Forest using a function that would replace NaNs by a mean value or an outlier value.

In your case, it could be -1 or -5, but you can use the general mean value so that it would reduce the variability for NaN values in the classification process.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer


X_train = [[1,4,5,3,5,1,8,5,1,0, NA, 6],....
Y_train = [lung,...
X_test_1 = ...


# Option 1: Create our imputer to replace missing values with the mean e.g.
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imp = imp.fit(X_train)
X_train_imp = imp.transform(X_train)

#Option 2:Or replace by an outlier value
X_train_imp = X_train.nan_to_num(-5)

# Then train the classifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
clf = clf.fit(X_train_imp, Y_train)
    
#Option 1:
X_test_imp = imp.transform(X_test_1)
#Or Option 2
X_test_imp = X_test_1.nan_to_num(-5)

#Result:
print(X_test_1, '->', clf.predict(X_test_imp))
```

Initial source code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317119/classifiers-in-scikit-learn-that-handle-nan-null

Answer (score 1):

you can make various models,

1. the simplest is probably grouped-lasso - there are multiple implementation both in R and python - for example [this one](https://group-lasso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/example_group_lasso.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-example-group-lasso-py)

you turned your data into

```
R1 1,4,5,3,5,1, 8,5,1,0, NA, 6, lung
R2 5,NA,5,5,1,0,0.9, NA, NA,0,0,0,lung
R3 1,1,1,9,4,2,1,1,5,8,1,4 colon
```

and make group_id where you know which columns where together, in your example `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]`.

```
gl = GroupLasso(
    groups=groups,
    group_reg=5,
    l1_reg=0,
    frobenius_lipschitz=True,
    scale_reg="inverse_group_size",
    subsampling_scheme=1,
    supress_warning=True,
    n_iter=1000,
    tol=1e-3,
)
gl.fit(X, y)
```

2. architect your own model through bayesian framework - it refers to hierarchical bayesian model - make sure you are using Stan a higher level framework to translate what you want. Look [here](https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/radon.html)
3. Deep learning based model

[this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/72380/what-is-the-preferred-approach-for-this-problem/72537#comment99260_72537) sounds very similar

Comment: The last link you mentioned looks very useful. So if I want to keep 5 variables for each feature as show in example, do you think a model like randomForest would be suitable? Just want to test something simple before making it complicated.

Comment: @user120159 - yes, the simplest way is  forget the intra-connectivity and similar to what Nicolas has suggested feed to random forest or lasso or any other model.